# How to read logs?

Tags: logs

This might be little vague question, but how do you make logs more readable? Each time Craft runs, tons of log text is generated. Most of it is probably not related to specific problem one is trying to debug.

Do you have some solution for filtering stuff that is not interesting for you in logs? Or some specific syntax highlighting maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of Yii 2 log parsers and integrations with 3rd party logging services you could use https://packagist.org/?query=yii2%20log such as [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/), [Papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/), [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash), etc.

Comment: Thanks, just connected graylog and it works. Althought i also plan to test other log gathering services. Do you, as Craft Dev have some favourite one?